# Compile error with clang and libstdc++

Tags: c++, clang, libc++

I'm trying to compile with clang a large codebase that we used to compile with gcc.

The following code

```
#include <queue>
#include <functional>

using T = int*;

using Func = std::function<bool(T const, T const)>;
using PQ = std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, Func>;

PQ GetPQ()
{
    Func comp = [](T l, T r) -> bool { return *l < *r; };
    return PQ(comp);
}
```

compiles just fine with

```
clang++ -S -std=c++14 aaa.cpp -stdlib=libc++
```

but fails to compile with

```
clang++ -S -std=c++14 aaa.cpp
```

This is the error that I get:

```
In file included from aaa.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/queue:60:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/deque:60:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/predefined_ops.h:123:23: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'std::function<bool (int *, int *)>'
        { return bool(_M_comp(*__it1, *__it2)); }
                      ^~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/type_traits:2346:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization '__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<std::function<bool (int *, int *)> >::operator()<int *, int *>' requested here
      std::declval<_Fn>()(std::declval<_Args>()...)
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/type_traits:2357:24: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template '_S_test' [with _Fn = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<std::function<bool (int *, int *)> >, _Args =
      (no value)]
      typedef decltype(_S_test<_Functor, _ArgTypes...>(0)) type;
                       ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/type_traits:2362:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__result_of_impl<false, false, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<std::function<bool (int *, int *)> >, int *, int *>' requested here
    : public __result_of_impl<
             ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/functional:1981:35: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::result_of<__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<std::function<bool (int *, int *)> > (int *, int *)>' requested here
               typename _Res2 = typename result_of<_Func(_ArgTypes...)>::type>
                                         ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/functional:2053:30: note: in instantiation of default argument for '_Callable<__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<std::function<bool (int *, int *)> > >' required here
               typename = _Requires<_Callable<_Functor>, void>>
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/functional:2054:2: note: in instantiation of default argument for 'function<__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<std::function<bool (int *, int *)> >, void>' required here
        function(_Functor);
        ^~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/predefined_ops.h:130:14: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'function' [with _Functor = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<std::function<bool (int *, int *)>
      >, $1 = (no value), $2 = (no value)]
    { return _Iter_comp_iter<_Compare>(__comp); }
             ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/stl_heap.h:385:28: note: in instantiation of function template specialization '__gnu_cxx::__ops::__iter_comp_iter<std::function<bool (int *, int *)> >' requested here
                       __gnu_cxx::__ops::__iter_comp_iter(__comp));
                                         ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/stl_queue.h:414:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::make_heap<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int **, std::vector<int *, std::allocator<int *> > >, std::function<bool
      (int *, int *)> >' requested here
      { std::make_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp); }
             ^
aaa.cpp:12:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::priority_queue<int *, std::vector<int *, std::allocator<int *> >, std::function<bool (int *, int *)> >::priority_queue' requested here
    return PQ(comp);
           ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/functional:2195:12: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'int *' for 1st argument; remove *
      _Res operator()(_ArgTypes... __args) const;
           ^
1 error generated.
```

Clang and libstdc++ versions:

```
$ clang++ --version
    clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
$ /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep stdc++
    libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    libstdc++.so.6 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

I'd rather not switch to libc++, and I think that (correct me if I'm wrong) this should work. Probably it's just a compatibility issue with the versions that I'm using but I haven't managed to find anything on the Internet so far. Any ideas as to what might be the problem?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please avoid making type-aliases for basic types, or type-aliases that are pointers. Those makes the code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Sure. That's not the real code, it's sort of a minimum working sample. I replaced the name of a class with an int and a shared_ptr with a raw pointer without paying much attention to these things. But thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Seems to work for me here https://wandbox.org/permlink/068g4dzWE17A21cR,  can you reproduce the error on that website?  It allows you to customize the compiler options

Comment: It works for me too (and it also works in Ideone), but it doesn't allow choosing the libstdc++ version.

Comment: @Curious wandbox doesn't seem to implement clang correctly. If you specify It `#include`s /opt/wandbox/clang-3.9.1/include/c++/v1/queue instead of whatever g++/libstdc++ provides, regardless of -slibstdc++ or --gcc-toolchain option.

Comment: This surely looks like a clang++ bug to me. Note the program compiles fine in c++11 mode. It also compiles if you add `-D_GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR=` compilation flag. This doesn't look reasonable to me at all.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, you are right, `clang++ -S -std=c++11 aaa.cpp` works fine. I take it you can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes I can reproduce it.

Comment: I've got **exactly** the same issue, heave you already fixed you compilation error?

Comment: @PaulYakovenko Sorry for the late answer. Adding the flag `D_GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR=` did the trick.